# Mongoose - search in array with array

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have following model

```
var reservationSchema = new Schema({
   lcode: Number,
   reserved_days: [daySchema],
});

var daySchema = new Schema({
    pk: Number,
    date: String,
    price: Number,
    payment_type: String,
    payment_date: String,
    room: { room_id: String, name: String }
});
```

I have a reservation with array of reserved_days. I need to compare this reservation and reservations in database and find reservation where at least one reserved_days date or reserved_days room.room_id are the same that contains in array. Array must not be fully equal, I just need to find duplicate days.

Now I try the following

```js
Reservation.find({
  $or: [{
    "reserved_days.room.room_id": {
      $in: req.body.reservation.reserved_days
    }
  }, {
    "reserved_days.date": {
      $in: req.body.reservation.reserved_days
    }
  }]
}).exec(function(err, found)
```

but it doesn't work.

Test request reservation.reserved_days object looks the following

```
"reserved_days": [
    {
        "pk": 3543,
        "date": "2018-07-14",
        "price": 3213.0,
        "payment_type": "Безналичный расчет",
        "payment_date": "2017-12-28",
        "room": {
            "room_id": "7",
            "name": "Стандарт"
        }
    },
    {
        "pk": 3544,
        "date": "2018-07-15",
        "price": 3213.0,
        "payment_type": "Безналичный расчет",
        "payment_date": "2017-12-28",
        "room": {
            "room_id": "7",
            "name": "Стандарт"
        }
    }]
```

Is it possible to do ?

Comment: What do the test record(s), req input look and current output/error look like? Also, are you intentionally checking the `room_id` with the `reserved_days` array?

Comment: yes, intentionally. updated with request data